# Jquery prop value change on submit won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$( function() {
    $( "#save-chart-form" ).submit( function( event ) {
        $("#saveChartButton").prop( 'value', 'Please be patient' );
        // event.preventDefault() // works with this
        // $('#save-chart-form').submit(); // Doesn't work
    } );
} );
```

I run this on a form #save-chart-form when #saveChartButton is clicked.
So the text of the button is changed to 'Please be patient' when button is clicked.

This doesn't work at all unless I put a `preventDefault` event.
Is there no way to have any jQuery action performed on form submission? 
I tried many other solutions that all fail. Also I can't get `$('#save-chart-form').submit()` do anything, which would be a solution. I'm using jQuery 3.1.1

EDIT: It's a browser issue: it works correctly on Firefox. Safari doesn't process anything after unload request as mentioned by Rory McCrossan.

Comment: Use val() not prop() to set the value.

Comment: Why woulld you resubmit the form inside a the form submission? It is already submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because in most browsers the UI will no longer be updated once a request to unload the page is made (ie. the form submission has been made). A workaround would be to change the button text under the `click` event of the button itself, instead of the `submit` event of the `form`. Try this:

```
$("#saveChartButton").click(function() {
    $(this).prop('value', 'Please be patient');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gwqmxaed/)

Note that the change is only visible for a small time before the page is unloaded.

Comment: Indeed, moreover, this problem affects only Safari, I don't get it in firefox. I got caught by a same kind of problem yesterday :/

Comment: It can be browser specific. I can see the same behaviour in Chrome. Updated to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `$('#save-chart-form').submit()`. It's redundant.

```
$(function(){
    $("#save-chart-form" ).submit(function(event){
        $("#saveChartButton").prop('value', 'Please be patient');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to show the text "please be patient" in other HTML element and not the #saveChartButton , because changin the value of a form element that is already submitted can be confusing to the js engine.

e.g.

```
$("#save-chart-form").submit(function(event) {
    $("#msgBox").html('Please be patient');
});
```